# React and django cache issue

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a react and django app which is being served behind nginx. The /admin route and /api routes both point to uwsgi. However when loading these routes the react app is served unless a hard refresh of the page is peformed. It seems like react is serving all routes instead of just the index.

Is there a way to exclude routes in react so it will only display if the path is "/" or is there something in nginx/django config I can change to overcome this issue.

This is a snippet from my nginx conf:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /api/ {
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
```

and my django urls config:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include(routers.urls))
]
```

Any ideas on how I could proceed would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like React is intercepting the `onClick` event of the links and preventing the browser from handling it normally.

You can try altering the link tags so that they prevent React from doing that:

```js
<a href="/admin/" onClick={() => { location.href = "/admin/" }}>Admin</a>

/* Or if using react router */
<Link to="/admin/" onClick={() => { location.href = "/admin/" }}>Admin</Link>
```

> Is there a way to exclude routes in react so it will only display if the path is "/"…

How are the routes added or configured in React? They should be changed to use the format I illustrated above, or deleted if you don't want them to display at all.

> … or is there something in nginx/django config I can change to overcome this issue.

Your nginx configuration is written correctly. You can [test it here](https://nginx-playground.wizardzines.com/#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).

Comment: I don’t have a button for the admin currently I just access it via the url “https://host/admin/“ there are not routes configured in react it’s just a one page application with one view

Comment: @Dylan.evans007 if you open up a new tab and go directly to the url `https://.../admin/` it is responding with the React page? Maybe you're missing the trailing forward slash after admin `admin/`?

Comment: Opening up a new tab and going to admin/ in an incognito window returns the django admin. But going to admin/ in a new tab when not in incognito returns react. It’s almost like react is being cached

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution.

1- update your react-scripts to ^v4

2- add urls you don't want to be cached to service-worker.js file:

```
registerRoute(
   ({ request, url }) => {

      ...

      if (
         url.pathname.startsWith('/admin') ||
         url.pathname.startsWith('/api')
      ) {
         return false;
      }

      ...

      return true;
   },
   createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);
```